# How to set ComputeCpp_DIR properly?

Tags: opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2019, cmake-gui

I recently installed ComputeCpp to `D:/Programs/Codeplay/ComputeCpp`. Then I set `ComputeCpp_DIR="D:/Programs/Codeplay/ComputeCpp"` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file for compiling OpenCV. I use `cmake-gui.exe` to configure build options and to generate the project files for Visual Studio 2019.

After each time I press `Configure` in `cmake-gui.exe`, the variable `ComputeCpp_DIR` is reset to `ComputeCpp_DIR-NOTFOUND`. The value `"D:/Programs/Codeplay/ComputeCpp"` is correct according to the official guide at https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/, i.e. *"This should be set to the root directory of the ComputeCpp install (i.e the directory with the folders bin, include, lib)"*. The specified path does not contain any white space characters either. I also tried to modify `build/CMakeCache.txt` directly, but `cmake-gui.exe` keeps resetting my setting.

I wonder why?? How can I get cmake to accept my setting, which is apparently correct.

Comment: Since `ComputeCpp_DIR` is used as **cache** variable, it should be set in the `CMakeLists.txt` as CACHE one: `set(ComputeCpp_DIR "D:/Programs/Codeplay/ComputeCpp" CACHE INTERNAL "...")`

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev. Unfortunately it did not help. However, I found the solution: I created an empty ComputeCppConfig.cmake file in D:/Programs/Codeplay/ComputeCpp . After that cmake-gui stopped overwriting my setting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add an empty `ComputeCppConfig.cmake` file into the `D:/Programs/Codeplay/ComputeCpp` directory. After that `cmake-gui.exe` will stop overwriting your setting.